# Parse send push notifications to users that are in two channels

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using parse to handle push notifications. I've added channels based on the city the user is in and the gender of the user. I want to send a push notification to all male users in LA. However, when I create two separate channel conditions in the parse dashboard, the "number of devices that the push will be sent to" is way off. For example:

When I add the condition for the channel "users in la" it says there are 1400 devices.

Then I add a separate condition for the channel "male", and it updates the number of devices to 4000. Note that I am creating two separate channels here, not adding both channels to the same condition, but it still appears to be performing an `or` instead of an `and`.

Comment: Channels are ORed. You will need to use advanced targeting with a query. The query can be against the channels in PFInstallation

Comment: Can I write out queries on the parse dashboard? Or will I need to call the rest api myself with the advanced query in it?

Comment: I don't think you can use the dashboard to OR conditions

Comment: I see -- i just changed it such that instead of creating channels for gender, i just tag the installation object with "female": true, or "male": true. These conditions get and'ed in the dashboard...weird that they don't support and'ing channels in the dashboard though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used tags for conditions that I wanted to and -- the webview does not support and'ing between channels.